# What Bootstrap setting causes this vuetify treeview node broken to two lines?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, treeview, vuetify.js

I created a test ASP.NET MVC 5 web project using VS 2019. Then I added VueJS 2.6.14 and Vuetify 2.6.12 into the project and created a v-treeview page using the data from this link [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=101).
The normal treeview shows like this:
[image: normal treeview]

But somehow my MVC view page shows it like this:
[image: Tree node is broken into two lines]

I have tried to change HTML tags width in the Chrome DevTool but there is no fix.
I guess some Bootstrap setting causes the strange show. But I don't know what setting causes this.
Please post your answers if you had the issue and fixed it.

The sample code is posted below.

```
    public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vue").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/vue-2.6.14/vue.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/vuetify-2.6.12/vuetify.min.js"
                  )); 

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/vuetify-2.6.12/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
<div id="app">
<p><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openComm()">CommView</button></p>
<v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview ref="tree"
                :items="items"
                :search="search"
                :active="activeNode"
                :open.sync="open"
                @@update:active="nodeClicked"
                activatable
                hoverable>
    </v-treeview>
</v-app>
```

```
        new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify({
            iconfont: 'mdi' //'mdiSvg', // || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4' || 'faSvg'
        }),
        data: {
            search: '',
            open: [5,6,7],
            activeNode: [8],
            allOpened: false,
            lastOpen: [],
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Applications :',
                    children: [
                        { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
                        { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
                        { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Documents :',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            name: 'vuetify :',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    id: 7,
                                    name: 'src :',
                                    children: [
                                        { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                                        { id: 9, name: 'bootstrap : ts' },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the Vuetify's CSS in bundle config.cs as below.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
      "~/Scripts/vuetify-2.4.6/vuetify.min.css",
      "~/Scripts/vuetify-2.4.6/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
      "~/Content/site.css"));
```